# If $M$ is not connected and locally connected such that $M=A\cup B$, show that $A,B$ are open in M

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $M$ not connected and locally connected ($M$ metric space). If $A,B\subset M$ are connected, disjoint and non-empty such that $M=A\cup B$, then $A,B$ are open in $M$.

Here's my attempt:

$M$ is not connected and hence one can find $P,Q$ , disjoint, such that $M=P\cup Q$. Since $A,B$ are connected and disjoint, we must have (wlog) $A\subset P$ and $B\subset Q$. We notice that for every $a\in A$, $P$ is an open set containing $a$. Since $M$ is locally connected, for every $a\in A$ exists open $V\ni a\subset P$ connected. Again by $V$ being connected, it follows that $V\subset A$, which shows that $A$ is open. The same argument may hold for $B$. And this prove that $A,B$ are open.

Is this all-right? Am i being careless with something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need $M$ to be locally connected. If you have $A \subset P$ and $B \subset Q$ with $M = A \cup B = P \cup Q$, then it follows that $A = P$ and $B = Q$. Simply take some $x \in P$, then either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. But if $x \in B$, then it is also in $Q$ which can't be the case because $P$ and $Q$ are disjoint. So we have $x \in A$ and thus $A = P$, making $A$ open.

In fact you could generalise this statement to the following:
Let $M$ be a topological space with a finite amount of connected components. Then all of its components are open.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes i really tought that would be the case: $A=P$ and $B=Q$, but i didn't believe in my intuition since i wasn't using all given hyphotesis.